# Distorted screen image leads to unresponsive laptop

Tags: laptop, troubleshooting, acer-aspire

My computer screen suddenly image gets distorted and starts to tremble left & right.   There is no response when I move the Mouse or press Alt,Ctrl, Del. I managed to "trigger" it to start/stop by pressing on the left bottom edge of my laptop. It seems like a hardware (Motherboard perhaps?) problem.
Also, the laptop doesn't startup always after this occurs.
Laptop type: ACER aspire V3-571 (windows 10/64 bit, for completeness)

Any insight is highly appreciated.

I will try to post a picture of the symptom as soon as I get the laptop running.

Comment: Take it to a repair shop.

Comment: I am not this kind of guy :P But I might consider it if there's no alternative. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Perhaps power problem needing better earthing?

Comment: @harrymc also did it when not connected to external power. But, could be.

Comment: First, download the *maintenance/repair* manual. 2. Disassemble. 3. Look for loos connectors, particularly one that migh be nudged by pressing on l-b edge. 4. If that didn't fix it, then you need skills to repair surface-mount components and a micro-soldering station.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution to the above problem. It was either caused by a loose connector or by speckles of dirt (sand or so) short circuiting the legs of a particular IC on the mainboard. During the investigation I couldn't locate any obvious loose connections, so I cannot rule it out, but I believe that cleaning the board helped a great deal.

The steps I followed where:

1. Opened the laptop and disconnect all connectors to the mainboard (always follow steps in service manual)
2. Removed the mainboard from the PC case and performed a visual inspection at both sides of the motherboard(used my smartphone camera with flashlight ON). I focused particularly at the southwest corner (both top & bottom sides) of the motherboard where I suspected that the root cause lied.
3. Gently brushed the dust out of all electronic components using paint brush.
4. Removed dirt/stains by dipping brush in alcohol.
5. Reassembled all parts.
6. Started up computer and tried to trigger issue by pressing & gently deforming laptop case; failed to reproduce issue.

Currently it works OK and I am monitoring it.